# Can JSON data dynamically specify an angular filter to use?

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular (v1.2) app that accepts JSON data and displays it in a table using a set of ng-repeats and a structure defined by another JSON object. Within the structure, I specify the filter using an ng-switch.

data JSON:

```
[
    {
        first: "Lorem",
        second: "Ipsum",
        arg: 2
    },{
        first: "Dolor",
        second: "Sit",
        arg: 3
    },{
        first: "Amet",
        second: "Consectetur",
        arg: null
    }
]
```

structure JSON:

```
[
    {
        key: "first",
        filter: "lowercase"
    },{
        key: "second",
        filter: "uppercase",
        rgmnt: "arg"
    }
]
```

HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in data">
    <td ng-repeat="cell in structure" ng-switch on="cell.filter">
        <span ng-switch-when="lowercase" ng-bind="row[cell.key] | lowercase: row[cell.rgmnt]">
        <span ng-switch-when="uppercase" ng-bind="row[cell.key] | uppercase: row[cell.rgmnt]">
        <span ng-switch-default ng-bind="row[cell.key]">
    </td>
</tr>
```

But this seems sloppy. For one, you need to specify the filter name in two places, in the script and in the html. It would be simpler if you could pull the filter name from the data, like this:

```
<td ng-repeat="cell in structure" ng-bind="row[cell.key] | cell.filter: row[cell.rgmnt]"></td>
```

Is there any way to dynamically pull a filter name from data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can specify the filter id dynamically:

```
<div ng-repeat="nextItem in data" ng-bind="nextItem.name | {{nextItem.filter}}"></div>
```

See working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WCNPMrLZqCAmkqeFRmKK?p=preview).

**EDIT**: You may want to set a default filter or no filter with a simple workaround:

**Create a new filter which just returns the input:**

```
app.filter("same", function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input;
    };
});
```

**Modify the ngBind**

`ng-bind="nextItem.name | {{nextItem.filter ? nextItem.filter:'same'}}"`

See final [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WCNPMrLZqCAmkqeFRmKK?p=preview).

Comment: But what if the item doesn't need or specify a filter? In such a case, it would populate as `<ng-bind="nextItem.name | ">`, which would error out and display nothing.

Comment: Turns out you can use another filter to display the pipe if it exists! This makes the code: `ng-bind=nextItem.name {{nextItem.filter | ifFilter}}` with ifFilter having: `if (input != null) { return "| " + input; }`

Comment: If you are interested in another solution, look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to himmet-avsar!

The filter can specified simply by using handlebars.

```
<td ng-repeat="cell in structure" ng-bind="row[cell.key] | {{cell.filter}}: row[cell.rgmnt]"></td>
```

But, this assumes that the filter property is always specified. You can use another filter to specify if the pipe is shown and even pass arguments through it:

```
<td ng-repeat="cell in structure" ng-bind="row[cell.key] {{cell.filter | isThereAFilter: row[cell.rgmnt]}}"></td>

function isThereAFilter() {
    return function (input, arg1) {
        if (input != null) {
            return "| " + input + ": " + arg1;
        }
    }
}
```